# Most efficient way to implement this nav effect?

Tags: html, css, navigation, mouseover

I'm trying to achieve [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCWlI.png) mouseover effect with the smallest footprint possible.  I can't get the arrow (.png) to display, it gets cut off by the height and I'm not sure how to get the height to show. I've tried several failed methods so far, hoping someone can help me out.

What I've done is style the anchor for the box and try to position the small arrow below the box. The arrow isn't displaying outside of the box in the anchor, it gets cut off.  I tried making the arrow the part of the LI, it worked but because the anchor needs to be 30px (height of the blue box) and the LI needs to be 40px (box + the height of the arrow 10px) it will display the arrow if you mouse over that 10px area and not the box.

currently it [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3JWc.png).

Here is my css:

```
#navlist {
float:right;
}
#navlist li {
line-height:40px;
display:inline;
list-style-type: none;
margin-right: 20px;
}
#navlist li:hover {
background:url(../img/navArrow.png) no-repeat center;
background-position:50% 30px;
}
#navlist li a {
height:30px;
padding:3px 5px 3px 5px;
color:#26627f;

}
#navlist li a:hover {
background:#035173;
border-radius:3px;
color:#fff;
}
```

and here is the html:

```
<ul id="navlist">
    <li><a href="#">Get a Quote</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Learn about Life Insurance</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Our Company</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Get Help</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Put your (relevant) HTML and CSS into a live demo, [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, that we can see in action, and work with.

Comment: here you go :: http://jsfiddle.net/LQDVP/  Is it possible to include images in a jfiddle? I don't have the rep to include this with my post unfortunately..

Comment: It's certainly possible to include images, but, obviously, you'll need to provide an absolute, rather than a relative, URL to the required images. Also, I'm not sure where the border comes from, in your first image. So while I've posted an answer that works (in most browsers, including, I think, IE9 and *possibly* 8), I'm unable to include that border.

Comment: The border in the first image is not necessary as that was just clipped in from the mockup.  It was simply the box+arrow effect I was trying to get.  I'll imgur the arrow and update the fiddle to include its path. Check the jfiddle now for the image path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply add the following to your CSS:

```
#navlist li:hover a::after,
#navlist li a:hover::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0 0 0 -1em;
    border: 1em solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #035173;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LQDVP/2/).

This does, of course, require that the user have a browser that implements CSS generated content and pseudo-elements.

---

**Edited** in response to comment from OP, in comments below:

> Not really sure how you are getting a shape out of that, care to explain? It works. Is there any way to make the arrow smaller and can it take a box-shadow effect?

It works because the border of an element meet at 45°, and because there's no `height`/`width` for the element that produces a triangular shape 'pointing' towards the centre of the element (or, in this case, the pseudo-element). If all four borders were visible you'd have a square; if top and bottom were visible you'd have a triangular 'hourglass,' and so on.

To make the triangle smaller, simply assign a smaller unit to the border-width (in the example above the borders are set to `1em`, simply change it to `5px` or, well, any other size and unit of measurement that the browser can implement.

The negative margin-left (the `-1em` in the `margin` declaration) has to be equal to the `border-width` in order to place the pseudo-element centrally along the horizontal axis, but it can be adjusted to taste.

To add a `box-shadow` is difficult, since all four borders have to be assigned to create the triangular shape, the `box-shadow` would be a rectangle for the whole element, not just the 'visible' part of it. It can be emulated, if you're okay about using another pseudo-element, in this case the `::before`, but it won't have the usual 'fuzziness' of a genuine `box-shadow`, but, as a demonstration, simply copy the above CSS, amend the `::after` to `::before` (and make sure the `::before` element occurs *before* the declaration for `::after`, as the later-declared element will be above the previously-declared element). Adjust the margins and the `border-top-color` properties and it should look okay-ish:

```
#navlist li:hover a::before,
#navlist li a:hover::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0 0 0 -0.7em;
    border: 1em solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #ccc;
}

#navlist li:hover a::after,
#navlist li a:hover::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0 0 0 -1em;
    border: 1em solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #035173;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LQDVP/4/).

Comment: Not really sure how you are getting a shape out of that, care to explain? It works.  Is there any way to make the arrow smaller and can it take a box-shadow effect?

Comment: My only regret is that I have but a few upvotes to give. Thanks a shitton, very creative solution!